# Merge contacts deletes left hand user in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, duplicate-contacts, user

I'm working with a new membership site and have migrated the data.  When members renew, if the email address is different, it creates a new contact, as expected.  So I have been merging a few contacts in Civi.  At the top of the merge screen it says:
"
WARNING: There are WordPress user accounts associated with both the original and duplicate contacts. Ensure that the WordPress user you want to retain is on the right - if necessary use the 'Flip between original and duplicate contacts.' option at top to swap the positions of the two records before doing the merge."

So I keep the Wordpress user on the right, check the fields to merge and then complete the merge.  However, the wrong Wordpress user is kept linked, and not the one associated with the Civi record on the right.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think the wording needs updating. What matters is the checkbox at the very bottom of that screen that takes the left user and moves it over to the right. If it's checked then the user account on the left now gets associated with the contact on the right.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the workaround to this.  If I make sure that I have transferred anything from WooCommerce (that is what we use) to the new user within Wordpress and then delete the Wordpress user that I don't want, I can then merge the accounts in Civi and keep the account in Wordpress linked that I want.  It's a bit more of a faff but at least it is possible for an admin user to do this.

Does anyone use WooCommerce CiviCRM?  It's very good but could do with some enhancing so I hope I'm not the only one still using it...

Comment: I'm sure Andrei et al would be more than happy to enhance it if you've got the resources to make that happen.